# Trouble with my css link "Tag start is not closed"

Tags: html, css

i have this error in my stylesheet link "Tag start is not closed"

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Codedaddies List</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This is not a CSS issue, but the framework you use on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see what wrong with your link

```
<a href=" " />
```

This is self-closing anchor tag here the href takes the link or path inside double inverted comma i.e " "

Now in your link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
```

Here compiler takes href as

```
href="{% static "
```

which is inside double inverted comma and as soon as it discovers / (forward-slash) it thinks this / as the closing of link and expects for >.This is the reason its throwing error and giving unclosed tag error.

What the compiler is expecting

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/>
```

This is the solution :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

make sure you css/style.css is inside single inverted comma ' '